# collapsible div with arrow in bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a big div and I want to place an arrow in the bottom of the div to either collapse or open the div. When the div is opened, then it works fine as the arrow goes to the bottom and as there is padding-bottom for the paragraph.

However, when the div is collapsed, the arrow is on top of the div. I want the arrow to appear little below the last line in the collapsed div. How do I do that here?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-jasper-4xlv3j?file=/src/App.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="bruh-introduce-koti" :class="{ isBigPara: openParagraph }">
    <div class="bruh-koti-header">
      <div class="">Introducing</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bruh-info-block">
      <div class="bruh-paragraphs">
        <p>
          {{ firstParagraph }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ secondParagraph }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bruh-arrow-container">
      <i
        class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"
        @click="openParagraph = !openParagraph"
      ></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      firstParagraph:
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
      secondParagraph:
        "Watch this video to know more about why and how you can leverage. kotis and expand your generosity circle.",
      picture: "https://picsum.photos/500",
      openParagraph: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.bruh-koti-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.bruh-introduce-koti {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e6eaea;
  background: rgba(245, 247, 246, 0.59);
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 25px 16px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.bruh-info-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 20px;
  gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.bruh-koti {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
.inner-container {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.bruh-koti-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.isBigPara {
  height: 85%;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
.bruh-arrow-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.bruh-paragraphs {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.arrows {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Change `height` of `.bruh-introduce-koti` to `238px`.

Comment: I think you have to bring the ".bruh-arrow-container" outside the ".bruh-introduce-koti" container since this parent container has "overflow: hidden" and which is important to keep that way. So no matter how you position the arrow you will not be able to see it when it is outside the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Second Solution: If you want the arrow within the box but with some space below the text then you can do it in a simple but tricky way.

You have to add 16px extra height to the bottom of the box so that the text remain the same in the initially collapsed state. And then use that extra space as a background color of that arrow container. Here are the changes:

```
.bruh-introduce-koti {
  height: 166px; /* 150 + 16 (height of the arrow container) */
}

.bruh-arrow-container {
  background: #f9fafa; /* Same background color as the box */
}
```

Here is the updated codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-grass-7yrvzr

First solution:

Bringing `.bruh-arrow-container` outside the `.bruh-introduce-koti` does work. Also it was needed to make it's `position: static` so that it can move with the above box when it expands or collapses. Here are the working codes:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="bruh-introduce-koti" :class="{ isBigPara: openParagraph }">
      <div class="bruh-koti-header">
        <div class="">Introducing</div>
      </div>
      <div class="bruh-info-block">
        <div class="bruh-paragraphs">
          <p>
            {{ firstParagraph }}
          </p>
          <p>
            {{ secondParagraph }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bruh-arrow-container">
      <i
        class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"
        @click="openParagraph = !openParagraph"
      ></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      firstParagraph:
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
      secondParagraph:
        "Watch this video to know more about why and how you can leverage. kotis and expand your generosity circle.",
      picture: "https://picsum.photos/500",
      openParagraph: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.bruh-koti-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.bruh-introduce-koti {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e6eaea;
  background: rgba(245, 247, 246, 0.59);
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 25px 16px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.bruh-info-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 20px;
  gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.bruh-koti {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
.inner-container {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.bruh-koti-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.isBigPara {
  height: 85%;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
.bruh-arrow-container {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.bruh-paragraphs {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.arrows {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution but the arrow is not inside the grey box at the end

Comment: OK, got it and updated in the answer. Please check once again.